# what is this error in phonegap/cordova in command line....?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am new in phonegap .. when i am start this in command line then show me this error in this i learn in this link [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqFpfrUrMM4)

```
c:\users\worspace\hello\cordova platform add android
    creating android project...
    c"users\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                            thro e;
    Error: Faild to run "android".make sure you have the latest android SDK installed and that the "android" command <inside the tools/folder> is add to your PATH.
        at C:\users\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4package\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:43:27
        at exithandler<chid_process.js:654:7>
        at chidProcess.emt <events.js:95:17>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error because Android is not defined to your machine, this means that your paths are not right, so for **ubuntu or mac** all you have to do is to update bash profile file with corresponding paths. I think that **PATH=${PATH}:Android/sdk/platform-tools:Android/sdk/tools** is not right, it should be absolute path to these folders. something like:

```
export PATH=/Users/your_user/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/tools/:/Users/your_user/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk/platform-tools/:$PATH
```

Comment: sir that's my Path....C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\Compressed\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\tools;C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\Compressed\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\platform-tools;C:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin

Comment: Please try to test 'android' command in your command prompt, if this not working then you have a problem with your path

Comment: in upper all path are set that they are required... in you tube link.. than what can i do for this

Comment: Yes but you have to make sure that android command is working, can you just type 'android' in your cmd and back to me with the output

Comment: when i put the android in cmd the show this----->'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
c:\users\Owner\Downloads\Compressed\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\tools>

Comment: Can you move the whole folder to D: or any other directory then update paths to be sure that is not permissions issue

Comment: i have change the ADT path and again install the node.js,JDK, and ADT but this error show me again...... and my path in user variable  and system variable.........What can i do ->C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;D:\android\ADT\sdk\platform-tools;D:\android\ADT\sdk\tools;C:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin

Answer (score 1):

You need the Android SDK installed and accessible from the command line to add Android as a platform.

If you haven't installed them, go here and follow install instructions: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools

If you already have, make sure the folder containing the `android` command is in you PATH.

([Detailed instructions for adding to PATH](http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/))